# Passing input to predefined URL path parameter in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am new to react, redux and axios. I am using the library to make calls to a backend. I would like to make a request with a template like `/api/posts/:id`. After reading the documentation it seems that axios support only query string parameters by using the `params` property. Is there any solution in which I could pass the parameters using the library, aside from the obvious solution of adding the parameters myself to the url?

Comment: What's wrong with using the `params` object?

Comment: You can append on the URL or use params https://github.com/axios/axios#example

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu the params object is used for query string params. The request would look like  `api/posts?id=someid`

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to send to `api/posts/:id` and not in query string like `api/posts?id=someid` and if that is the case then you can create the url yourself and hit it as :

```
const url = 'api/posts/' + id;

axios.get(url)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said in the question I do not want to construct the url myself.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any library that provides that feature.

Comment: Having angular experience this feature is somewhat common for me.

Comment: If you are creating or defining routes for your application then only you can simply define `/api/posts/:id` and  configure whatever html  you need to render but if you are making an ajax  request then I don't think that it will contruct by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, there's no native predefined string formatting by object in js. You'll have to rely on string templating library such as lodash.template, mustache.js, handlebar.js.

Example:

```js
/**
 * Formatting string using lodash
 * install it by:
 * $ npm i lodash.template
 */
const template = require('lodash.template');

const compiled = template('/api/posts/<%= id %>/other/filter/<%= encodeURIComponent(name) %>/<%= nested.id %>');
let output = compiled({id: "12345678", name: "<good bot>", nested: {id: "777"}});
console.log(output); //output: "/api/posts/12345678/other/filter/<good bot>/777"
```

But in your case, this pose a problem: lodash doesn't offer an option to escape strings other than HTML, you'll have to escape it either in your template (as demonstrated with `encodeURIComponent(name)` in code above), or your object's value.

Another option is using mustache.js, overwrite the mustache HTML's escape function:

```js
/**
 * Formatting string using mustache
 * install it by:
 * $ npm install mustache --save
 */
const mustache = require('mustache');

mustache.escape = (value) => encodeURIComponent(value);
const output = mustache.render(
    '/api/posts/{{id}}/other/filter/{{name}}/{{nested.id}}',
    {id: "12345678", name: "<good bot>", nested: {id: "777"}}
);

console.log(output); //output: "/api/posts/12345678/other/filter/%3Cgood%20bot%3E/777"
```

Then you can now pass `output` to axios.

Answer (score -4):

You can send GET parameter as a second argument in axios.

The Syntax:

```
axios.get(url[, config])
```

An example:

```
axios.get('/api/posts/', {
  params: {
    id: 12345
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Your approach will  not append the id to the url(pass it as url param), instead it will append it to request query params resulting in a request like : /api/posts?id=12345